# Krull dimension of the local ring at the generic point of a divisor is 1.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, localization, divisors-algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

Let $X$ be a nonetherian integral separated scheme which is regular in codimension one, i.e. every local ring $\mathscr{O}_x$ of $X$ of dimension one is regular.

Let $Y$ be a prime divisor, i.e. a closed integral subscheme of codimension one. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$, meaning the closure of $\{\eta\}$ will be $Y$. Hartshorne claims that $\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}$ is a discrete valuation ring (*Algebraic Geometry*, page 130) without even any sketch of a proof so I try to fill the gap and understand the valuation of a prime divisor better.

My question is, how to show that $\dim\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}=1$? If this is shown then $\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}$ is automatically a discrete valuation ring.

When $X$ is an integral scheme of finite type over a field, for a closed subset of $X$, we have
$$
\operatorname{codim}(Y,X)=\inf\{\dim\mathscr{O}_{P,X}:P \in Y\}.
$$
But this does not apply to a noetherian scheme because noetherian scheme is not necessarily of finite type over a field. However, I wonder if it is possible to associate the dimension of $\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}$ to the codimension of $Y$ over $X$.

Comment: The identity $\operatorname{codim}(Y, X) = \operatorname{inf}_{P \in Y} \operatorname{dim} \mathcal{O}_{P, X}$ holds for an arbitrary scheme $X$ and a closed irreducible subset $Y \subset X$. This can be found in section 5.8 of the book "Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes" by Gortz and Wedhorn.

Comment: @eggplant Great, that section goes beyond answering my question! I will put down the content below to increase its accessibility. By the way the book looks good and the logic chain concerning (co)dimension is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

One finds the following text on *[Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes - With Examples and Exercises](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-658-30733-2)* by Ulrich Görtz and Torsten Wedhorn, section 5.8 (thank @eggplant for the reference) that answers the question neatly:

> If $X= \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Z=V(\mathfrak{p})$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, the codimension of $Z$ is also called the *height* of $\mathfrak{p}$. It is the supremum of lengths of chains of prime ideals of $A$ having $\mathfrak{p}$ as its maximal element. This implies easily that for an arbitrary scheme $X$ and a closed irreducible subset $Z$ with generic point $\eta$ we have
> $$
> \operatorname{codim}(Z,X)=\dim\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}=\inf_{z \in Z}\dim\mathscr{O}_{z,X}.
> $$

If we put $Y$ into the identity above we get $\dim\mathscr{O}_{\eta,X}=1$.